# Finding Nearby Features using Tile38

Tags: geospatial, tile38

I'm trying to use the Tile38 database to search for closest features to a given point and radius, based on the documentation [https://tile38.com/commands/nearby], it should find the nearest features within the radius provided and should be ordered based on the distance to the point, but by using the following nearby query, it is not producing the expected out come.

**Tile38 Data:**

```
# OSM WAY 1

SET LRS_TEST OSM&&WAY10592122 FIELD meta '{"feature":"WAY","layer_id":"WAY","feature_id":"OSM&&WAY10592122","vicmap_road_names":["GARDINERS CREEK TRAIL","CITYLINK","UNNAMED"]}' OBJECT '{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[145.0352298,-37.8374751],[145.0349665,-37.8374204],[145.0347479,-37.8373876],[145.0344542,-37.8373537],[145.0342236,-37.8373346],[145.034013,-37.837324],[145.0338078,-37.8373198],[145.0335839,-37.8373219],[145.0333626,-37.8373304],[145.0331507,-37.8373431],[145.0329643,-37.8373621],[145.032747,-37.8373886],[145.0325713,-37.837414],[145.0323943,-37.8374469],[145.0321448,-37.8374988],[145.0318029,-37.837575],[145.0315467,-37.8376343],[145.0312879,-37.8376894],[145.0310827,-37.8377339],[145.0308949,-37.8377678],[145.0306723,-37.8378038],[145.0304939,-37.837826],[145.0303169,-37.8378451],[145.030128,-37.8378619],[145.0299588,-37.8378674],[145.029759,-37.8378684],[145.0295414,-37.8378635],[145.0293322,-37.8378507],[145.0291689,-37.8378332],[145.0289908,-37.8378107],[145.0287668,-37.8377738],[145.0284598,-37.837689],[145.0281995,-37.8376017],[145.0280017,-37.8375254],[145.0277925,-37.8374397],[145.0276122,-37.8373553],[145.0274176,-37.8372527],[145.0272614,-37.8371596],[145.0271053,-37.8370584],[145.0269363,-37.8369281],[145.026669,-37.8367093],[145.0265103,-37.8365467],[145.0263191,-37.8363432],[145.0259387,-37.8359123],[145.0254405,-37.8353373],[145.0248245,-37.8346331],[145.024076,-37.8337694]]},"feature_id":"OSM&&WAY10592122","layer_id":"OSM","feature_type":"LINE","properties":{"Hex Index":[604314936591515647]}}'


# OSM WAY 2

SET LRS_TEST OSM&&WAY10592129 FIELD meta '{"feature":"WAY","layer_id":"WAY","feature_id":"OSM&&WAY10592122","vicmap_road_names":["GARDINERS CREEK TRAIL","CITYLINK","UNNAMED"]}' OBJECT '{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[145.0242202,-37.833699],[145.0249771,-37.8345629],[145.0255818,-37.8352643],[145.0261807,-37.8359464],[145.0263563,-37.8361408],[145.0266897,-37.8364842],[145.0269932,-37.8367649],[145.0271473,-37.8368942],[145.0274437,-37.8370893],[145.0276962,-37.8372252],[145.0279431,-37.8373415],[145.0282033,-37.8374456],[145.0284439,-37.8375247],[145.0286924,-37.837598],[145.0289724,-37.8376538],[145.0292708,-37.8377009],[145.0295253,-37.8377236],[145.0297765,-37.8377265],[145.0300567,-37.8377233],[145.0303277,-37.8377053],[145.0305851,-37.8376725],[145.0308601,-37.837629],[145.031135,-37.8375761],[145.0315011,-37.8374903],[145.031764,-37.8374268],[145.0321489,-37.837341],[145.0324144,-37.8372869],[145.032684,-37.8372425],[145.0329562,-37.8372064],[145.0332164,-37.8371842],[145.033499,-37.8371691],[145.0337609,-37.8371651],[145.0340264,-37.8371715],[145.0342987,-37.8371863],[145.0345682,-37.8372086],[145.0348405,-37.8372467],[145.0350497,-37.8372816],[145.0352732,-37.8373251]]},"feature_id":"OSM&&WAY10592129","layer_id":"OSM","feature_type":"LINE","properties":{"Hex Index":[604314936591515647]}}'


# OSM WAY 3

SET LRS_TEST OSM&&WAY756852509 FIELD meta '{"feature":"WAY","layer_id":"WAY","feature_id":"OSM&&WAY756852509","vicmap_road_names":[]}}' OBJECT '{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[145.0290871,-37.834018],[145.0289588,-37.8340363],[145.028506,-37.8339769],[145.0283699,-37.8339298]]},"feature_id":"OSM&&WAY756852509","layer_id":"OSM","feature_type":"LINE","properties":{"Hex Index":[604314936591515647]}}'


# OSM WAY 4

SET LRS_TEST OSM&&WAY756852510 FIELD meta '{"feature":"WAY","layer_id":"WAY","feature_id":"OSM&&WAY756852510","vicmap_road_names":["MORRISON STREET"]}' OBJECT '{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[145.0283699,-37.8339298],[145.0285162,-37.8339201],[145.0289616,-37.8339774],[145.0290871,-37.834018]]},"feature_id":"OSM&&WAY756852510","layer_id":"OSM","feature_type":"LINE","properties":{"Hex Index":[604314936591515647]}}'


NEARBY LRS_TEST LIMIT 1 WHEREIN meta.layer_id 1 WAY IDS POINT -37.834040127081664 145.02898743753536 5.0
```

**To Reproduce**
Use the above commands to get the output

**Expected behavior**
Expected behaviour is to provide me the closest road to the point provided in the NEARBY, and it should produce this output ["OSM&&WAY756852509"],  but currently, it gives ["OSM&&WAY10592122"] for ids instead of.

[image]

**Additional context**
Tile38 Docker compose:

```
  tile38:
    image: tile38/tile38:latest
    container_name: tile38
    volumes:
      - tile38-data:/data
    ports:
      - 9851:9851
    network_mode: bridge
```